# How do I convert an array of integers to an array of strings based on the value of the integer?

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I have an array of integers that I'm randomizing using a method, and I want to convert that array of integers using

```
    int[] prizesUnshuffled = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
    RandomizeArray(prizesUnshuffled);
    String[] prizesString = (generateStringArray(prizesUnshuffled));
```

What I want is for instance, the unshuffled array to then be

```
    String[] prizesString = {PrizeA, PrizeA, PrizeA, PrizeB, PrizeB, PrizeB, PrizeC, PrizeC, PrizeC, PrizeD, PrizeD, PrizeD, PrizeE, PrizeE, PrizeE, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF, PrizeF};
```

Sorry if I'm bad at explaining this, but I have no clue how to accomplish this, as I'm new to using arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8's Stream API can make this a trivial one-liner:

```java
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
String[] arr_toString = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().map(x -> "Prize" + x).toArray(String[]::new);
```

If you don't have access to the stream API, or would prefer something else, you can also do:

```java
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
String[] arr_toString = new String[arr.length];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    arr_toString[i] = "Prize" + arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Lol was just about to post my Streams answer until I saw that yours was identical

Comment: This is close, I realize that I should have specified that I want the strings to be unique. I have strings PZL, MPT, PSR, GME, BAL, DLL, with proper text that I want to replace the numbers with.

Comment: Without further information, we can't help you. Why not update your question with an example of certain input, and what output you're looking for. That way, you can specify the transformations done to the input to turn it into the output, based on your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] generateStringArray(int[] prizesUnshuffled) {
    // Create string array of same size as we are going to return the same size
    String[] stringArr = new String[prizesUnshuffled.length];
    String prepend = "Prize";

    // Sort the prizesUnshuffled as it's been randomized by RandomizeArray
    Arrays.sort(prizesUnshuffled);

    // Iterate till there are items in prizesUnshuffled
    for (int i = 0; i < prizesUnshuffled.length; i++) {
        // Concat the string with prizedUnshuffled
        // Replace it in generate string array
        stringArr[i] = prepend + prizesUnshuffled[i];
    }
    return stringArr;
}
```